# Flask error after adding csrf protection - Python

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms, prometheus-python-client

I got the following sonar issue under security hotspots:

[image]

Sonar recommended the following fix:
[image]

So I added the following code:

```
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
...
app = Flask(__name__)  # unchanged
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = os.urandom(32) # added because "RuntimeError: A secret key is required to use CSRF."
csrf = CSRFProtect()
csrf.init_app(app)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)  # unchanged
```

Now I'm getting a Flask error in my code:

```
INFO:flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF token is missing.
ERROR:main:Exception on /my_api/getData [POST]
.
.
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tempuser\Documents\Git\my-api\venv_py38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1541, in finalize_request
    response = self.process_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tempuser\Documents\Git\my-api\venv_py38\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1885, in process_response
    response = self.ensure_sync(func)(response)
  File "C:\Users\tempuser\Documents\Git\my-api\venv_py38\lib\site-packages\flask_prometheus_metrics\metrics.py", line 40, in after_request
    request_latency = time.time() - request._prometheus_metrics_request_start_time
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute '_prometheus_metrics_request_start_time'
```

I'm not sure why other dependencies are failing. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to add crsf token into your client side. If you're enabling crsf - every request to your backend must include crsf token

For example:

```
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <button type="submit">Sumbit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The python service/API is used by non-browser based apps so I am testing through postman. I added `X-CSRF-TOKEN=secretkey` header to postman and also changed `app.config['SECRET_KEY'] ="secretkey"` in the code but still getting the same error. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: then create additional GET request like that:
```
@app.route('/my_api/get_token', methods=['GET'])
def get_token():
    csrf_token = generate_csrf()
    return jsonify({'csrf_token': csrf_token})
```

Firstly you're gonna send get request to get csrf token and after that you're gonna paste it in your POST request:
```
'csrf_token': csrf_token
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the explanation. I couldn't get this working so I exempted all the blueprints and routes with `csrf.exempt()` method ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯